# Undefined class Request in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, request, facade

I am using the Laravel Request Facades, however my import is being flagged by my IDE (PhpStorm 8) as undefined.

```
use Request;
```

I'm new to the idea of Facades, but am not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the instances you get from the Facades are resolved dynamically, use this package that generates a file that provides accurate class definitions that PHPStorm can understand:

> [Laravel 5 IDE Helper Generator](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper)

Comment: Cheers! Nice quick fix to an error I wasn't sure how to solve.